# Correctly zipping two columns with different data types in cuDF

Tags: python, rapids, cudf

I have the following DataFrame in cuDF:

```
                                                 Context                                          Questions
0      Architecturally, the school has a Catholic cha...  [To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear ...
1      As at most other universities, Notre Dame's st...  [When did the Scholastic Magazine of Notre dam...
2      The university is the major seat of the Congre...  [Where is the headquarters of the Congregation...
3      The College of Engineering was established in ...  [How many BS level degrees are offered in the ...
4      All of Notre Dame's undergraduate students are...  [What entity provides help with the management...
```

The `context` column is a single string, whilst the `Questions` column is a list of strings. What I wish to obtain is a new column that represents the zipped versions as a list such as `[(Context, question_i)]`.

The following code works for the SQuaD-v.1 data-set:

```
data = cudf.read_csv(DATA_PATH)
pattern = '([^"]+\?)'

data["Questions"] = data['QuestionAnswerSets'].str.replace('Question\\" -> \\"', '').str.findall(pattern)
```

Obstacles: I do not wish to invoke the list constructor, as this would create memory transfers from device to host. Furthermore, when trying to use user-defined-functions, such as:

```
def zip_context_question_pairs(row):
    return row['Context'], row['Questions']

df = df.apply_rows(zip_context_question_pairs,
                   incols=['Context', 'Questions'],
                   outcols={'Context_QuestionPairs': 'object'},
                   kwargs={})
```

This will error as you can not use UDF's on different data types. How do I correctly zip the string and list into a new column whilst still having data on device?

To reproduce:

```
df = cudf.DataFrame({
    'context': 'Architecturally, the school has a Catholic character.',
    'question': [['To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear?', "another question"]],
    })

context = df["context"][0]
questions = df["question"][0]

desired_result = []

# This for loop is what I would like to transform to a cuDF method to avoid lists 

for question in questions :
    desired_result.append((question, context))

print(desired_result)
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you want one row per `Questions` list (what your UDF implies) or one row per question in each `Questions` list (what your use of `_i` implies). You may be able to do this by exploding the list column and then creating a new column. If you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it may be easier for people to provide suggestions.

Comment: @NickBecker I would like each row to represent the zipped version of (context, question). I will update the question with a MRE.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `explode` operation.

```py
import cudf

df = cudf.DataFrame({
    'context': 'Architecturally, the school has a Catholic character.',
    'question': [['To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear?', "another question"]],
    })

df.explode("question")
context     question
0   Architecturally, the school has a Catholic cha...   To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear?
0   Architecturally, the school has a Catholic cha...   another question
```

Comment: Thanks! This creates two rows, where I would preferably have this in only one row. The desired result is what should be in the single row. The reasoning is that I am using cuDF's subword tokenizer which expects a Series, and I can not create a cuDF from exploding and .loc[0] on that dataFrame.

Comment: Are you sure your minimal example is what you want? When I ran it created two rows.

Comment: The desired result is a list that I wanted to to parse into a single cuDF dataframe row.